# Problems installing github

Tags: r

Hi I have a problem with github package. 
   This is my code:

Installing packages:

```
install.packages("magrittr")    
library(magrittr)

install.packages("ggplot2") 
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("cowplot")
library(cowplot)

install.packages("usethis")
library(usethis)

install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
```

Here comes the error , when I try to force the installation:

There are 4 options: 
1: All
2: CRAN packages only
3: None
4: tibble (2.1.3 -> 3.0.0) [CRAN]

When I press 1 I get this error message:

> Installing 1 packages: tibble
>       Installing package into ‘C:/Users/josem/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

```
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
tibble  2.1.3  3.0.0              TRUE

Error: Failed to install 'JLutils' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘tibble’ is in use and will not be installed
    devtools::install_github("larmarange/JLutils", force= TRUE)


install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

library(JLutils)
library(tidyverse)

install.packages("rio")
library(rio)
```

Then when I choose option 3 I can download jutils package but I can not create dat2 dataframe. I don't know why. It's really frustrating ( yesterday it worked perfectly)`

```
dat <- rio::import("https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/blob/master/docs/reportes_minsa.xlsx?raw=true")

dat1 <- dat %>%
  mutate(pos_new = Positivos-lag(Positivos,default = 0),
         des_new = Descartados-lag(Descartados,default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Dia) %>%
  summarise(pos_new = sum(pos_new), des_new = sum(des_new)) %>%
  mutate(cum_pos = cumsum(pos_new),
         tot_pruebas = pos_new+des_new)
```

Here is the error:

> (creating dat2):
>   Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Dia' not found

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  mutate(neg_new = tot_pruebas-pos_new) %>%
  dplyr::select(Dia, pos_new, neg_new) %>%
  rename(Positivo = pos_new, Negativo = neg_new) %>%
  gather(res, count, -Dia) %>%
  uncount(count)
```

I tried everything :(

Comment: Whenever R say *"package ‘...’ is in use and will not be installed"*, this is unfortunately you cue to restart R and try again. If you have unsaved work, consider `saveRDS` or `save` to save your objects to disk somewhere.

Comment: Try loading packages in this order to see if it helps: `library(JLutils); library(rio); library(tidyverse)`

Comment: @Tung Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Dia' not found. Same error :(

Comment: Worked fine for me. I used `openxlsx::read.xlsx()`. `library(openxlsx); 
dat <- read.xlsx("https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/blob/master/docs/reportes_minsa.xlsx?raw=true")`. the rest of the code worked.

Comment: `> dat2; 
# A tibble: 13,452 x 2
     Dia res     
   <dbl> <chr>   
 1 43896 Positivo
 2 43897 Positivo
 3 43897 Positivo`

Comment: `tibble      * 3.0.0; tidyr       * 1.0.2.9000; dplyr       * 0.8.99.9002`